# Calculate Whole from Fraction

Tags: percentages, ratio

The goal is to calculate the total of a statistic which has only percentages but no absolute numbers. It is known that the values of total and all percentages are integers.

I want to find all values behind the percentages, which are whole numbers (integer) this should be possible with the rule of three.

I dont come from maths so sorry for the incorrect notation of the equaiton. I do mostly code, but i thought I'd better ask before I code something stupid.

The goal is a function which loops thru all values of `n`. if the function of `total` is an integer, then this is a possible value for `n`.

```
p     (percentage)     = 5.2
n     (possible value) =  13 (and multiples of 13)
total (unknown)        = 250
```

[image]

Am I on the right path or completely wrong? Your help is highly appreciated, wether it is a hint or a complete new approach.
Best endo

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you speaking of, say, the Batting Average problem (wherein, knowing a player's BA, one attempts to determine the number of At Bats that this represents)?  Something else?  For that problem, to stress, the issue is rounding, as BA's are rounded to three places.  Is that the issue you mean to address?  What does this have to do with "integration"?

Comment: So you want to convert a percentage as a decimal into a ratio? This is trivial. Say we have 5.2% as in your example. We would then write $52/1000$ and reduce to lowest terms. In this case that's $13/250$. Once you're done looping you'll need to find the lowest common denominator among those ratios to reconstruct the smallest possible total.